# collect metrics for uncaught exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, agent

I want to collect metrics for those uncaught exceptions, I do it by a java agent ,So Which class should I enhance?
If I want to collect those exceptions may I just enhance the constructor of exception ,but how could I pick those uncaught exception?

Comment: See `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 1):

[Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-)

```
Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler, new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    // record information about uncaught Exceptions and Errors here.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank for your advice！

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible.

The problem is in the definition. Define 'uncaught exception'.

### Technical

Technically there's no such thing. Exceptions are always caught by something, eventually. They bubble up the stack, ending methods immediately, recursively applying that principle (end this method right now, going back to the method one up the stack. End that one right now, go back to the method one further up. Endlessly. Or until we hit a catch block, which **you always will**).

Thread itself will catch it if it has to. It then invokes the uncaught exception handler with it. You can configure it using `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`. There's no need to use agents to call that method.

However, inject something as simple as, say, an appserver or web server, and usually their 'endpoint runner' (the thing in the framework that invokes your code) will catch it all.

So, how do you define 'uncaught'? Does an exception that bubbles up to the webserver endpoint runner count as 'uncaught'?

If you say 'yes, that is uncaught', you have a few problems:

1. You need specific knowledge and modify the webframework to figure this out. You'd have to write it for every web framework or at least customize your 'uncaught exceptions counter' for every appserver-ish thing your stack uses.
2. This will also count, say, an IOException caused by the sender because they hung up the connection halfway through sending HTTP headers, and ServletExceptions - i.e. things that **are designed to be handled by the webserver endpoint runner**. I assume the point of this 'uncaught exceptions counting system' is to find and eliminate such things, but then you have a false positive issue. These exceptions should absolutely not be 'handled' - what is currently happening (that they end up at the webserver runner that handles them) is correct.

If you say 'no, that means they are handled', then your app is useless, as that means everything is handled. Because those endpoint runners catch Throwable. (and are correct in doing so).

So, the technical approach isn't feasible. Unless you just want to stop stack traces showing up on sysout. Then, just use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`. JVMs start with an uncaught exception handler that just prints the exception type, message, trace, and causal chain to `System.err`. You can override it with one that does something else, no problem. Do it as first thing in your `void main()` method. No need to bother with agents.

### Pragmatically

Instead of trying to focus on some sort of technical definition, we can talk about what you actually mean by 'an unhandled exception', which is generally: An exception that code ought to be handling, but doesn't.

The problem is, that, as a concept, is completely unbound from anything you can technically measure. For example, take this code:

```
public void saveGame() {
  try {
    Files.write("symersAwesomeGame001.sav", gameState.asBytes());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

If I take a microphone to a java conference, show them the above code, and ask: "Soo, what do you say? Did the author of this code handle I/O exceptions?", the vast majority of respondents would give the correct answer. Which is **NO** - that isn't appropriate at all.

If the aim is to find places where exception handling isn't proper, this is exactly the kind of thing you want to find. But it's the opposite of the technical definition: The exception **is** being caught. But that's the problem: It's caught but not handled properly. The right move here is likely to make the `saveGame()` method declared as `throws IOException`, or possibly `throws SaveException`). Failing that, the catch block should read `throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);`.

Trying to write an agent to catch this stuff is somewhat possible, if you posit that 'a catch block that just prints stack trace is just wrong, period'. You can scan for that by parsing through class defs (scan the bytecode: Toss it through ASM or bytebuddy or some other bytecode introspection tool).

However, this job is far better suited to source-code-level linting. A linter rule should be set up to disallow catch blocks that just `e.printStackTrace()`. An advantage of this is that you can set up some comment that opts out of the linter - for the very few cases what `e.printStackTrace();` is a well thought out correct answer (it *very rarely* is, but situations exist, rare as they are, that it's right to do that).

Comment: Minor point: I like to throw Error instead of RuntimeException, as I see Error connoting "We've detected a problem, and it's not recoverable" whereas RuntimeException to me indicates an existing problem that needs to be fixed in the code... Just how I do it :-)

Comment: Thank you for your advice and detailed explanation! It has been very helpful to me. However, I cannot scan the codes directly because I want to enhance those apps using a Java agent. Therefore, it needs to be non-invasive. After reading your comment, I think it might be better to collect all exceptions.